am having an error in php Failed to open stream: No such file or directory '../config.php'.the last is a file to make a cnx with db
im a still a student , this is my first web project and am using the MVC strcuter
when i try to run the whole project this error comes'Warning: include(): Failed opening '../config.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\control\Specialite.php on line 2
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "config" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\control\Specialite.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\view\dashboard\pages\tables.php(6): specialiteC->afficher() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\control\Specialite.php on line 6'
i am having an assignement soon and am really desspered i didnt undrestant the problem

The problem is you've provided the wrong path to your config.php file, so the script can't find it to include it. Have you researched this error message at all? It's a common one and you should be able to find existing explanations and ways of fixing it. What specifically did you not understand about the messages?

https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed+opening+for+inclusion+php

Given that we can't see your system and cannot tell where you have placed that file (assuming it even exists), it's a bit unclear what assistance you are hoping for. Locate the file and then set the correct path to it relative to the script which is including it

For more background info and to get familiar with paths in php and how it all works, read a good guide such as https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

There are some Possible Solutions For You.

You can share your file structure So It will be easier to Understand the Problem
Probably You are facing Path declaration problem.
-> First Make Sure, Where your config.php is in If it is in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC', means the path of config.php is 'C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\config.php' and you are in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\control\Specialite.php', You supposed to add double back path indication for access the config.php like
include '../../config.php'; or include './../../config.php';

also You can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to declare your path if it is easier for you to get reach that file from the root directory.
You can see more from Here For Include PHP and other similar discussions

How do I set an absolute include path in PHP?
Way to get absolute path of file PHP
PHP how to find application root?

